# Inserting number after alphanumeric group not followed by numeric group

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that contains one or more alphanumerical codes (starting with a letter) separated with an underscore. Some codes are followed by an index number, which is also separated with an underscore.

I want to insert an index number (always 1) after each code that is not already followed by an index.

Here's some sample :

```
one                 =>  one_1
one_tw2_tre_for     =>  one_1_tw2_1_tre_1_for_1
one_tw2_tre_23_for  =>  one_1_tw2_1_tre_23_for_1
one_3_tw2_4_tre_45  =>  one_3_tw2_4_tre_45
```

I can do it with two calls to preg_replace :

```
// Add '_1' after each code
$s = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+/', '$0_1', $s);
// Remove '_1' when followed by index
$s = preg_replace('/_1_([0-9]+)/', '_$1', $s);
```

I'm wondering if there's a way two do it with only one preg_replace (I tried lookahead and lookbehind, without success) or a different way that might be faster, processor wise.

Thanks !  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+(?!_[0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9])/', '$0_1', $s);
```

Or, more concise:

```
preg_replace('/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+(?=_|$)(?!_[0-9])/', '$0_1', $s);
```

Comment: Ah-ha!  Now I understand the 'zero-width' note about lookahead!  I can have a positive one and a negative one that ends up checking the same character (in this case the '_').

Cheers !

Comment: Would you believe I was using them for 5 years before I realized I could combine multiples after each other. Oh the time I could've saved...